# IIS CORS, on JavaScript fetch request

Tags: iis, axios, cors

I have the CORS problem with `axios` or `fetch` with different configurations, these are my codes:

For `fetch`:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        Authorization: token,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
})
  .then(response =>
    response.ok ? response : Promise.reject<Response>(response)
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.Token)
```

Or for `axios`

```
axios.get(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  crossDomain: true
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log("sendValidateJWTRequest response", response);
  return response.data
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
  return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

And in my web.config I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm still getting in the browser:

[image]

What else should I try?

Comment: Your approach is wrong, as it cannot handle anonymous preflight requests properly. Use IIS CORS module please, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Answer (score 1):

As the comment posted by [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li), IIS CORS is a good choice to handle the CORS issue. some Preflighted requests can not be handled properly. In an Asp.net web application, we usually add a `global.asax` file to process it on the server-side.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.End();
            } 
}
```

However, IIS Core module is a better solution.
1.  Install the IIS CORS module on the server-side.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module
2.  Here is a common configuration allowing all requests from all origins.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="*" allowed="true">
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true"/>
            </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

That’s all.
For customizing your configurations for a specific origin, please check the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.